# Excel worksheets: summarize a bunch of sheets using indirect

Tags: sql, excel

**Current scenario**

- I'm a data tester, and I test insurance contracts, and each policy has many "roles", "features", "history items" etc.
- A standard SQL query with all data joined will return 20-30 rows all jumbled together
- We need a way to review each policy (aka contract) in an organized and systematic way
- So, instead of creating 1 big query, we create 7 related queries.  Each related query uses "contract #" as a PK (primary key).  We put all the queries in a workbook and we're well on our way.

**Issue**

- The problem is, we still have a lot of data processing to do, we can review each "policy" across all these sheets
- We need a simple, efficient and highly automated method to review our Excel workbook

Comment: I'm a tester.  I'm only a tester.   Everything I do is as a data quality assurance and/or software quality assurance tester.   The work in this post was 100% related to testing.   I have no idea why a few of you deemed it "...unrelated to testing"

Answer (score 1):

**solution**

- create a "summary" worksheet that connects all related worksheets
- this concept works for any data with a shared PK (primary key)
- all we're really doing is using standard VLookup functionality of Excel, but with an important twist
- instead of hard coding our VLookups we'll use Excel's INDIRECT function to execute our VLookups based on column headings
- the big advantage here is that we can add/remove/change columns and since our ODB (operational database) has 1,200 tables, we have a lot of variations (beyond the scope of this overly simplistic Q&A)

[image]

[image]